# not work Binding ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

i want to getimage users and show in ListView WPF/Csharp

i use of *Binding* for get values.

this is my code:

xaml:

```
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding InstaMedia}" 
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding [0].Images[0].URI}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

and C#:

```
 public partial class ProfileUserPage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ProfileUserPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private List<InstaMedia> _instsmedia;
    public List<InstaMedia> InstaMedia
    {
        get { return _instsmedia; }
        set
        {
            if (_instsmedia != value)
            {
                _instsmedia = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyNmae = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyNmae));
    }

    private async void Page_LoadedAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var GetPost = await user.GetUserMediaAsync(...); //this takes about 5 seconds for get images
        _instsmedia = GetPost.Value;         
    }
```

images user available in:

```
   _instsmedia[X].Images[X].URI
```

but this not work and Does not show anything in my ListView. how i can fix this?

pls help me..

Comment: `Source="{Binding Images[0].URI}"` should work. If not, show us your InstaMedia class. You should also use ObservableCollection instead of a List when you add items after the view has been initialized.

Comment: @Clemens not work. this is [InstaMedia class](https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper/blob/develop/InstaSharper/Classes/Models/InstaMedia.cs)

Comment: Please edit your question with the (relevant parts of the) class. Have you used ObservableCollection instead of List?

Comment: Have you set the correct DataContext?

Comment: As noted by Lennart, you would have to set the Page's DataContext to make `{Binding InstaMedia}` work. Alternatively, use `ItemsSource="{Binding InstaMedia, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}"`.